# JQUERY: save and restore attribute data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get/save all the elements that have attribute "tabindex".

Then, when the user clicks one element to open the popup, I need to set all the elements to "tabindex = -1" so when the user hits the tabkey they won't jump to all other fields that have "tabindex".

After the user closes the popup I need to restore all the tabindexes to each element.

So, for "tabindex = -1" I use:

```
$("*[tabindex]").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1'); });
```

But how can I save and the restore back for each element the "tabindex" was before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.data()` to save per-element data.

```
$("*[tabindex]").each(function (i) { $(this).data('tabindex', $(this).attr('tabindex')).attr('tabindex', '-1'); });
```

And then to restore:

```
$("*[tabindex]").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', $(this).data('tabindex')); });
```